# is $F_{k_{1}}(m)||F_{k_{2}}(F_{k_{1}}(m))$ always a PRF? when F is a PRF

Tags: encryption, symmetric

is $F_{k_{1}}(m)||F_{k_{2}}(F_{k_{1}}(m))$ always a PRF?  when F is a PRF

As an intuition it seems to me that the answer is "NO" as the two halves of the output depends on each other

Comment: Is it homework?

Comment: NOPE, philosophy thinking at midnight. @levgeni Im not even sure if it's provable.

Comment: What happens when two $F_{k_1}$ outputs collide, and what is the probability of that happening?

Comment: Not only this seems to be a secure PRF to me, I believe that even if you replace $F_{k_2}$ by a *weak* PRF (I.e. a PRF only guaranteed to look random on random inputs), the whole thing is still a PRF. Try writing the security proof, it's just two hybrids! (for the case with two PRFs at least - with a weak PRF it looks much harder and much less clear)

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau It is unclear that it works when $F$ is a weak PRF for me. You could imagine hard-coding a particular point $F_k(a) = b$ into a PRF. This will still be a weak PRF, as the probability that $a$ is uniformly chosen will be negligible. Applying this construction to the weak PRF will not yield a PRF though.

Comment: I was talking about using two different PRFs, a strong PRF F for the $F_{k_1}$ part, and a weak PRF F' for the $F_{k_2}$ part.

Comment: @Mark But if both parts are replaced by a weak PRF, then clearly (and provably) the full construction is not in general a strong PRF.